# there was any way to stop sending email to single member in queue salesforce

Tags: email, queue, public-group

How can we stop sending email for any specific queue member in salesforce

like we have list of queue member than I want to restrict the sending email to some queue member
How can achieve this please help me for this

Thanks

Comment: you want to restrict the sending of emails to ALL queue members or to a subset of queue members ? 
Because in the queue there is a checkbox available to not send emails to queue members.

Comment: Hi Chris, I want restrict the sending email to one member in queue and all other get email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot restrict sending email for single user in queue, either you would need to remove user from queue or restrict queue to receive any email notification.

To do so uncheck 'Send Email to Members' and put a dummy email address in 'Queue Email' field.
If you leave this field blank, then all the members of the queue will still receive emails.

Also you might want to review [How to stop email notification to Queue members](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdh2AUAR/fix-the-workaround-for-how-to-stop-email-notification-to-queue-members).